# Do I know the population or just a sample?

Tags: sample, population

I have to analyze an artifact (a pencil), more specifically I need to analyze the production of the last semester of 2021 (during 2022 the artifact is still being produced but in my analysis I'm not interested to the one not made in the last semester of 2021).

For each artifact made in the last semester of 2021 I know a variable, its length. Does this mean that I know the population or I just know a sample from the population?